# Creating an alias for apt-get update using apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, alias

I've noticed that a lot of blogs that I've seen advise updating the repos using `apt-get update` prior to running any `apt-get install`. Considering that many (most?) of my uses of apt-get involve an install, it never seems to hurt, and it only takes a few seconds, it seems to me that it may be worth creating an alias of `alias apt-get="apt-get update; apt-get"`. Being new to Linux and the command line in general, I can imagine that there are lots of things that I'm overlooking here, and I know that it's very easy to ruin a computer from the command line. Is there any particular reason to advise *against* this alias? (I know this might be closed as an opinion-based question. I want to clarify that I'm interested in solid fact-based advice rather than opinion.)

Comment: Advice: You generally don't need to run an apt update more than once a day, though there are exceptions. Most instructions include apt update simply because we don't know how long it's been since the user last did one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably considered best practice to run the update before you install software. However, the repositories aren't updated all that frequently and doing so will slow you down.

When you run `sudo apt update` you're updating your list of software that's available. As we don't know your update schedule, we suggest you run the command to ensure you're getting the most up-to-date packages available.

If you do not run the update, you may end up with older packages. The odds of this causing a problem are pretty low - but they are not zero. In most cases, they'll just update when you next update your software.

On the other hand, it's just a few seconds and it's not like you're required to pay much attention to it. You can simply run the command and keep doing what you were doing while the command runs.

As for your snippets for alias, you're probably looking for the `&&` function.

So, in your case, you'd want to alias this:

```
alias <your_word>="sudo apt update && sudo apt install"
```

Make sure you refresh your aliases after adding this. That may look like this:

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Now, when you want to install an application, you'll just use:

```
<your_word> <your_application>
```

For example, I just tested this and here's my command:

```
apttest leafpad
```

Which updated the repo information and then installed leafpad (a text editor). In my case, just to test the alias, I used the word 'apttest', but you can pick anything you want.

That will run `sudo apt update` and then run `sudo apt install <your application>`.

Switch the obvious to the obvious and don't include the brackets. The `&&` makes sure it finishes the previous command before running the second command. There may be more elegant ways to do this, but that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I always appreciate some guidance as I learn the ropes of Ubuntu and the Linux command line. My question does remain--is there any particular reason to _not_ set this alias, like is there a time that I wouldn't want to run the `update`?

Comment: There's no particular reason not to, though it'll possibly slow you down as the repositories aren't updated all that frequently. It won't slow you down significantly and it's good practice to update them first - though many of us don't follow best practices. I probably should have included that in the answer itself, but I got distracted with another post. My bad.

Comment: @KGill Please update the answer so I can give you the credit for answering the specific question. I appreciate the rest of the info.

Comment: @Yehuda Consider it done. While writing your answer last night, I was simultaneously answering a question about .rar files on Linux at the unix SE site. So, I completely missed the intro part while first writing up the fix for the alias command. Again, my bad.